# EDA explorer - artifact detection vs artifact correction

Tags: physiology, analysis

my question is related to this post -> [Open-source software for analyzing Electrodermal activity](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/16017/open-source-software-for-analyzing-electrodermal-activity/24053#24053)

The eda explorer, especially the online version, is quite nice and handy. However, it does not provide an automatic artifact correction, but “only” an artifact detection. In your text above, you described that “the noisy data can subsequently be removed”. I wonder how I can remove this noisy data. As far as I understand, I have to replace the noisy data points with clean data points. Otherwise, there are missing data points or the measurement time decreases by the amount of noisy data. Do you know what I mean? Maybe this is quite lame question, but I am struggling at this point.

I am looking forward to your help! Thanks a lot

Cheers TSM

Comment: I would be very pleased for an answer. Can anyone help me with my issue?

Comment: It's a bit late now, but usually in developed software and toolchains, artifact rejections refers to rejecting those epochs that have a detected artifact. If you are specifically interested in artifact, fieldtrip is a very common toolchain that is used, and it detects the artifacts by averaging and detecting abnormalities. take a look:  https://www.fieldtriptoolbox.org/tutorial/automatic_artifact_rejection/